# Batch Script- padding a "0" into script as well as few bug fixes

Tags: batch-file

Currently there are a few problems I am experiencing with the batch file I created.:

1) i been trying to implement padding to the file versions from 02-09 and for it then to resume like 10, 11 etc... for example the file created could be called delivery_20-11-17_02.txt but i need it to have padding so it will be  delivery_20-11-17_02.txt when it versions up. if it gets to version 10 it will need to stay like  delivery_20-11-17_10.txt.

2) When a new file is created it will save it like delivery_2017-11-09_.txt. For which there is an unnecessary underscore for the first version of the file at the end of it. i need that underscore to start once the files start versioning up from version 2 and not from the very first file created.

3) In the section of the code where i have the option to name a file there is also a bug which i'm unsure on how to resolve. For example i create the file and i choose to update filename and name it "cat" it willl be saved as delivery_2017-11-09_cat_02.txt. However I want this cat file to be  delivery_2017-11-09_cat.txt at first. then if i choose to update filename and name it cat again a version 2 will be created  delivery_2017-11-09_cat_02.txt. which is ok.

4) when i chose the option of "update version" a file would be saved like delivery_2017-11-09__2. a double underscore appears before the version number. I need there to be only 1 underscore their. I understand that this relate to a bit of question number 2.

Here is the code below in full:

```
@echo off

:prep
cls
set filename=
set mydate=
set newname=
set version=1
For /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%b-%%a)
set choice=

set filename="../delivery_%mydate%_%newname%.txt"
::set filename="../delivery_%mydate%_%version%.txt"
echo %filename%
pause

:_CHECKEXIST
cls
IF EXIST %Filename% ( 
    GOTO _MAINMENU 
) Else ( 
    GOTO start 
)
:_MAINMENU

ECHO.
ECHO Choose on of the the following options:
ECHO 1.   Update filename 
ECHO 2.   Update version 
ECHO 3.   Quit
ECHO.
SET /P Choice="Enter your selection. [1,2,3]: "
IF /I "%Choice%"=="1" GOTO addname
IF /I "%Choice%"=="2" GOTO versionup
IF /I "%Choice%"=="3" (
    GOTO _END
) ELSE (
    CLS
    GOTO _MAINMENU
)
:addname
echo Enter addition to file name
set /p newname=
set filename="../delivery_%mydate%_%newname%.txt"
echo File name is now %filename%.
::set choice3 =
::set /p choice3=(y / n)

::if '%choice3%'=='' ECHO "%choice3%" is not valid please try again

::if '%choice3%'=='y' goto versionup
::if '%choice3%'=='n' goto addname


:versionup
set /A version=version+1

echo version is %version%
::FOR /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%A IN ("%Var%") DO SET Var=%%A
set filename="../delivery_%mydate%_%newname%_%version%.txt"
if EXIST "%filename%" goto :versionup  

:start


echo.

echo Choose the following:
echo 1. Directories
echo 2. Files
echo 3. quit
echo.

set /p choice= 
if '%choice%'=='1' goto directory
if '%choice%'=='2' goto file
if '%choice%'=='3' goto end
cls
ECHO "%choice%" is not valid please try again
goto start


:directory
dir /ad /on /b > %filename%
echo. 
goto checksuccess


:file
dir /a-d /on /b > %filename%
echo.
goto checksuccess


: checksuccess
if EXIST %filename% ( 
    echo %filename% written successfully 
) else (
    echo file not written
)


:end
echo.
```

Comment: That is a lot of questions and a lot of code to dissect for one question. What section of code are we supposed to be looking at for each question?  I don't see any code where you attempt to pad any values with leading zeros.

Comment: The first question there isnt any code on there that is able to do padding. The other 3 questions not to particularly  sure how to solve them. within the code i presume it is to do with %filename%